# Send to all function. Multithreaded server

Tags: java, networking

So I've been building a small server ontop of this template server for practice. http://www.kieser.net/linux/java_server.html

Ive got  working client but I'm having difficulty working out how I can send a message from a client to the server and from that thread to all the other clients instead of only one client.

Can anyone shed some light on how I might go about this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? when i was doing a similiar thing, I kept a list of "doComs" objects that were created and then just called methods on the entire list. be carefull when removing doComs objects from list since usually that will happen on a seperate thread

Comment: I did try to make a class with a function that ha access to the main class and send things through a new output stream connected to the last doCom created. But this resulted in the first client sending to any clients after it but it would not recieve data from other any clients created after. I like your idea of a list of doComs. Could you elaborate on removing them please?

Comment: ok .. so in server when you create a new doCom object store it into a list. ( but now when storing/removing it other threads might be using the list so inorder to avoid concurrent modification exception you will need to lock the list). And when you get an exception in doCom you need to remove the doCom object from the list since exception would imply that you cant communicate with that channed

Comment: See my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115784/passing-a-parameter-to-all-running-threads/13116162#13116162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of this.. This should explain everything much better than i can :p

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/259777-a-simple-chat-program-with-clientserver-gui-optional/